# How to tell that a parametric curve does not intersect itself?

Tags: calculus, parametric

For example: if a curve is defined by
$x=3\cos{t}-\cos{3t}$, $y=3\sin{t}-\sin{3t}$, $0\le t \le \pi$

then $\frac{dx}{dt}=-3\sin{t}+3\sin{3t}$, and
$\frac{dy}{dt}=3\cos{t}-3\cos{3t}$

So, we can not say that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are monotonic function.
So, it may attain the same ordered pair.
how can I tell that it passes through each point only once?
please help me to understand. thank you.

Comment: Is there a pair $(x,y)$ that can be obtained with two distinct values of $t$ and, moreover, have a different derivative?

Comment: but how can i tell that there is no such pair $(x,y)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite the curve:

$(x_t,y_t)=(\cos{t}-\cos{3t},3\sin{t}-\sin{3t})=...=(\cos(t)(2-\cos(2t)),4\sin^3(t))$

Then, try to find $t_0\neq t_1$ such that $(x_{t_o},y_{t_0})=(x_{t_1},y_{t_1})$. Start with the second equation/coordinate and the solutions you obtain on this replace in the first equation/cordinate. You will get an answer to your question.

Comment: thank you so much sir

Answer (score -1):

Intersection of a curve with itself can be found using
$$ \{ (t_0,t_1) \in R \times R| x(t_0)=x(t_1), y(t_0)=y(t_1), t_0\neq t_1 \}$$

Comment: can u please tell me what will happen if there is no intersection?

Comment: if there's no intersection, the filters after $|$ will fail to produce any output and you cannot find $(t_0,t_1)$ pair that satisfies the conditions.

Comment: That is nice. thank you sir.

Comment: To me, this answer is missing crucial details on *how* to use that set.  Compare with "Counterexamples to the Riemann Hypothesis can be found using $\{z\in \mathbb{Z}: z = \frac{1}{2} + bi\text{ with } b\in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \zeta(z) = 0\}$."